# Asp:Button - if OnClientClick = True | False

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<asp:Button ID="Invoice" runat="server" Text="Create Invoice" OnClientClick="CreateInvoice_Click()" OnClick="CreateInvoice_Click1"/>



        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                   function Create_Invoice() {
                    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 180,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Create: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                              //code needed here
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                </script>



    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure?</p>
```

So user presses the 'Create Invoice' button, pop up appears allowing the user to select 'Create' or 'Cancel'.

The 'CreateInvoice_Click' function is run on code behind if the user clicks 'create' or 'cancel'. What I want to know (which needs to go inside the 'cancel' function') how do I say ignore the OnClick="CreateInvoice_Click1" if cancelled is clicked.?

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 2):

if you want to prevent the server side function from execution you simply need to return false in your client side function.

```
function Create_Invoice() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 180,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Create: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
              //code needed here
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;// that's all what you need
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, although cant test it because for some reason whenever the 'Create Invoice' button is clicked it jumps straight to the 'CreateInvoice_Click1' in code behind, before the user has selected an answer? Any ideas as to why?

Comment: if you want to make quick test. just use this::OnClientClick="return false;".

Comment: OnClientClick="return false; doesnt load the pop up, while OnClientClick="return true; loads the pop up and enters the 'CreateInvoice_Click1' in code behind b4 the user selects an answer, any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: i just want to explain my idea which is if you want to prevent server side event just return false.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are tryign to recreate something javascript does with a built in function.

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Leave tizag.com?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
    else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
    }
}
```

Taken from http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php

Comment: yeah but isnt that still going to run the onClick when it bounces back to the button, even though the user is re-directed to google?

Comment: In your button, set **OnClientClick="if (confirmation()) return false;"**. And in **function confirmation()** return the value of **var answer** after the if/else block, i.e. **return answer;**

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for the misunderstanding I thought you were aking sonethign else...

Answer (score 0):

you should try manually calling the serverside click event by using javascript;

checkout the code inside `Create` and `Cancel` button;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('#test').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
              resizable: false,
              height: 180,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                 Create: function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                     // manually calling serverside click event
                     $('#buttonHidden').click();
                 },
                  Cancel: function () {
                     //code needed here
                     $(this).dialog("close"); 
                      // don't call it manually here and thus it won't fire the serverside click event
                  }
              }
         });
      });
    </script>
    // your button here to call javascript
    <button id="test" runat="server">Create Invoice</button>
    // the hidden button just to hold the CreateInvoice_Click1 which is fired from fireClick()
    <asp:Button ID="buttonHidden" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="CreateInvoice_Click1" />
```

your code behind;

```
 protected void CreateInvoice_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //your server side code

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="Invoice" runat="server" Text="Create Invoice" OnClientClick="return Create_Invoice()" OnClick="CreateInvoice_Click1"/>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Create_Invoice() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 180,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Create: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            },
            Cancel: function () {
              //code needed here
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
<p id="dialog-confirm"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure?</p>
```

your code behind;

```
protected void CreateInvoice_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//your server side code   


}
```